# installing PyQt4. "DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found."

Tags: python, pyqt4

I have seen this and simmilair problems all over the internet, but none of the solutions work for me.

I'm trying to install PyQt4 on my windows 10 64x. I'm running a 32x python 3.5.2.

I downloaded the binary package for PyQt. I installed it in `C:\Users\...\Python35-32\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4` Next, I tried to import it in python:

```
>>> from PyQt4 import QtGui
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
from PyQt4 import QtGui
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.`.
```

Further, I tried to download the source package of PyQt, which I then tried to install within CMD.

```
C:\Users\mitch>cd C:\Users\mitch\...\Python35-32\Lib\site-packages\PyQt-win-gpl-4.11.4

C:\Users\mitch\...\Python35-32\Lib\site-packages\PyQt-win-gpl-4.11.4>configure.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mitch\...\Python35-32\Lib\site-packages\PyQt-win-gpl-4.11.4\configure.py", line 27, in <module>
    import sipconfig
ImportError: No module named 'sipconfig'
```

So next I downloaded the source package for SIP, and tried to install it via CMD.

```
C:\Users\mitch\...\Python35-32\Lib\site-packages\PyQt-win-gpl-4.11.4>cd C:\Users\mitch\...\Python35-32\Lib\site-packages\sip-4.18.1

C:\Users\mitch\...\Python35-32\Lib\site-packages\sip-4.18.1>configure.py

C:\Users\mitch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Lib\site-packages\sip-4.18.1>configure.py
This is SIP 4.18.1 for Python 3.5.2 on win32.
The SIP code generator will be installed in
C:\Users\mitch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32.
The sip module will be installed in
C:\Users\mitch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Lib\site-packages.
The sip.pyi stub file will be installed in
C:\Users\mitch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Lib\site-packages.
The sip.h header file will be installed in
C:\Users\mitch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\include.
The default directory to install .sip files in is
C:\Users\mitch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\sip.
Creating siplib\sip.h...
Creating siplib\siplib.c...
Creating siplib\siplib.sbf...
Creating sipconfig.py...
Creating top level Makefile...
Creating sip code generator Makefile...
Creating sip module Makefile...
```

Next i tried to install PyQt again, hoping the sipconfig would be present this time. It wasn't.

```
C:\Users\mitch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Lib\site-packages\sip-4.18.1>cd C:\Users\mitch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Lib\site-packages\PyQt-win-gpl-4.11.4

C:\Users\mitch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Lib\site-packages\PyQt-win-gpl-4.11.4>configure.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mitch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Lib\site-    packages\PyQt-win-gpl-4.11.4\configure.py", line 27, in <module>
    import sipconfig
ImportError: No module named 'sipconfig'.
```

I tried to manually copy the file sipconfig from the sip directory to the PyQt4 directory, but that didn't work either.

I have added the PyQt4 directory to PATH. 
Also, i read online that some people had copied some files from PyQt4/bin. I do not have a bin directory in my PyQt directory.